# How to get vim p command to copy from the x session clipboard too?

Tags: vim

Hi I'm trying to paste into vim something I copied in my firefox web browser but unfortunately I have to enter insert mode and use `ctrl-v`, is there a way to get vim to use the global clipboard when I press `p` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

X has two ways to copy and paste text. Vim treats them both as registers, meaning you want either the `*` register, or the `+` register, depending on whether you just highlighted text in Firefox or actually copied (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>).  If the latter, the key sequence is:

```
"+p
```

If the former:

```
"*p
```

These are both done in normal mode, not insert or :-command mode.

See:

```
:help gui-selections
```